# AWS DMS - Migrate array from MongoDB to DynamoDB

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-dms

I'm trying to migrate data from MongoDB to DynamoDB. Based on my test, it seems DMS can only convert array into string. For example:

```
{ data: ['one', 'two', 'three']}
```

It will be

```
{ data: { 'S': [\"one\", \"two\", \"three\"] } }
```

Is it possible to convert it to `List` or `Set` using `object-mapping`? Or, there is already an official solution that I miss?

Comment: Yes, i'm using table mode.

Comment: Hey zeck, how did you end up doing that? I'm thinking about having lambda piped to output table that would be transforming arrays & dates.

Comment: How to transfer this type of data.  "SalesRep" : {
        "SalesRepName" : [
            "XYZ"
        ], 
        "SalesRepEmail" : [
            "abc@gmail.com"
        ]
    } in DynamoDB looks like: "array_SalesRep.SalesRepName": "[ \"XYZ\" ]",
    "array_SalesRep.SalesRepEmail": "[ \"ABC\" ]"